# encrypt in Javascript and decrypt in Java - Not working

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption

Iam encrypt in JavaScript and decrypt in Java but getting below error:

Error thrown in java:
java.lang.Exception: Given final block not properly padded

Below is my Java script code:

```
var key =CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("0123456789012345");
var ive  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("0123456789012345");

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, key, {iv: ive});
console.log('encrypted msg = ' + encrypted.toString());


var afterEncryptionText = encrypted.toString();
console.log("encrypted password: " + afterEncryptionText);
```

Java code:

```
public String decrypt(String cipherText) throws Exception {

    try {
        String encryptionKey = "0123456789012345";
        String ive = "0123456789012345";

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");

        final SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ive.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText.getBytes("UTF-8")),"UTF-8");

    } 
    catch(Exception e){

        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Iam not using Ajax. Iam just encrypting in Javascript and decrypt in java

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the representation of encrypted data as a String tends to lead to lossy conversions. When I attempted to convert the encrypted bytes directly to a String I would typically lose bytes or pairs of bytes which mapped to certain control characters.

I would recommend transmitting the bytes post-encryption directly. If that is not possible or you're not comfortable doing that, I would recommend representing the encrypted bytes as a number (say base-16 or base-64), transmitting a String containing the number, parsing the number at the receiving side, getting the bytes from that number by doing the inverse of the representing process and decrypting those bytes. This can be done, for example, using the `BigInteger` class, or you could write your own base-16 encoder.

Comment: not working . getting one more error: input length must be multiple of 16 when encrypting with padded cipher

Comment: And was this error thrown when using BigInteger or when custom encoding in base-16 or what? Also my bad for not clarifying, I meant you should encode only for transmission, not when encrypting and stuff too.

Comment: I did not use BigInteger . I transmitted without converting to toString(). the Java remains same. Now getting error: input length must be multiple of 16 when encrypting with padded cipher

Comment: In that case I would recommend that you write some code which converts one byte into two hex digits (you can read about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)) and transmits a String of hex digits generated from the encrypted bytes. Then at the other end, convert that String back into an array of bytes (do the opposite of converting bytes to hexes) and try to decrypt that.

Comment: Can you please provide me working code sample where encrypt in Javascript and decrypt in Java

Comment: My knowledge is not with Javascript unfortunately.